# MS Teams mobile (Android) bot attach image button is missing

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm developing a Chatbot with Bot Framework (Nodejs), and connect to Microsoft Teams channel

I can remember I test bot in MS Teams mobile (Android), and it used to have attach image button, but now button is missing

--**Note**--
Only Ms Teams mobile (Android) in private chat with bot 1:1 channel the button is missing, but chat with person and iOS is nothing

--**Image**--

[MS Teams Bot on iOS have upload image button (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddvEm.png)

[MS Teams Bot on Android have no upload image button (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6kbw.png)

Comment: This is not yet supported on mobile. We have raised an issue for this.

Comment: But I used to send image by mobile (Android), and currently on iOS it's work fine (have upload image button)

Comment: Attaching image as part of message body is supported. Could you please share screenshots of  issue you are facing?

Comment: I already shared screenshots

Answer (score 0):

You must create a Teams app that has a manifest. The manifest will contain [a setting to allow attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-files).

You can easily do this by using the App Studio Teams app. You can select and use your existing bot during this creation process. Under step 2, Bots, and Existing Bot, you would select "My bot supports uploading and downloading files"

Edit:

Here is what you would see on Windows after connecting the bot and talking with it:
[image]

Here is what you would see after creating a Teams app and configuring it to support files:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean Bot that create by Azure Bot Service and connect to channel MS Teams not support image uploading right ?

Comment: Correct. Just connecting a bot to Teams and then chatting with it will not allow you to send files. I'm not sure about iOS/Android, but on Windows you must create a Teams application that has a manifest. Without it and the setting [my bot supports uploading] you will not be able to sent files. I will update my answer with a few screen shots.

Comment: I agree with you about a bot Teams application that has a manifest but I don't want to create it, the problem is send image button (image not send file) missing, you know ? It used to have