# No attachments possible on teams bot on android

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

On Android devices Teams is not showing a paperclip to send images when talking to a bot?

Manifest has been configured with supportFiles: true

On iOS or Windows it was never an issue.

Its a blocking problem, since my customers wants to use Android devices.

Comment: @wajeed-msft Any idea on this one? Per this one way back when, you mentioned that it was not supported then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55945705/ms-teams-mobile-android-bot-attach-image-button-is-missing

Answer (score 1):

@sammydeprez Sending and receiving files through Teams Mobile App is not supported as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-files#send-and-receive-files-through-bot-on-teams-mobile-app).

Comment: Not on Android you mean? Since it is possible on iOS.
Any chance it will ever be supported?